# Problem with batch update using DataAdapter

Tags: sql-server-2005, ado.net, .net-2.0

I am updating the sql server 2005 database using batch update, as shown below

```
 cmd = new SqlCommand("update Table1 set column1 = @column1 where EmpNo = @EmpNo", con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@column1", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                cmd.Parameters["@column1"].SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
                cmd.Parameters["@column1"].SourceColumn = "Column";

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmpNo", SqlDbType.Int));
                cmd.Parameters["@EmpNo"].SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
                cmd.Parameters["@EmpNo"].SourceColumn = "EmpNo";

                cmd.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;

                sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter();
                con.Open();
                sqlDa.UpdateCommand =cmd;
                sqlDa.UpdateBatchSize = 10;
                sqlDa.Update(dt);

                con.Close();
```

But the data is not updated.I am unable to figure out what is the problem.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you look at the dt right before you issue the update command. Make sure there are some rows that have RowState of Updated or Added. If not, there's nothing in your (I'm assuming) DataTable to update to the database.

Also, try removing the .SourceVersion property set operation.

If everything looks good, start a trace on the database right before you issue the .Update.

These are just a couple first steps to try.

Answer (score 0):

SqlDataAdapter approach

using (SqlCommand insertCommand=new SqlCommand(

"INSERT BulkLoadTable(FieldA, FieldB) VALUES (@FieldA, @FieldB)", connection))

{
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@FieldA", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10, "FieldA");

```
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@FieldB", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "FieldB");
// Setting UpdatedRowSource is important if you want to batch up the inserts
insertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;
using (SqlDataAdapter insertAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
{
    insertAdapter.InsertCommand = insertCommand;
    // How many records to send to the database in one go (all of them)
    insertAdapter.UpdateBatchSize = myDataTable.Rows.Count;

    // Send the inserts to the database
    insertAdapter.Update(myDataTable);                   
}
```

}